# Why does it add .0 to the value while converting Dataframe columns to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

I have the following DataFrame:
df :

```
A   B   C   D
2   6   5   8.0
6   11  2   3.6 
1   5   7   5.2
```

to convert to JSON , I write following snippet:

```
df['total'] = df.apply(lambda i: i.to_json(), axis=1)
```

I get following output:

total

```
{"A":2.0, "B":6.0, "C":5.0, "D":8.0}
{"A":6.0, "B":11.0, "C":2.0, "D":3.6}
{"A":1.0, "B":5.0, "C":7.0, "D":5.2}
```

Why is that extra .0 is added to the result ?
How do I remove that extra .0 ?

Comment: That is because one of the values in the given row is a float so the entire row is interpreted as a collection of float values while calling `to_json`, You can try converting the entire dataframe to json `df.to_json(orient='index')` The output will look like `'{"0":{"A":2,"B":6,"C":5,"D":8.0},"1":{"A":6,"B":11,"C":2,"D":3.6},"2":{"A":1,"B":5,"C":7,"D":5.2}}'`

Comment: Works! but I need to process this df further for which I'm getting the error due to '{"0":{.....}, "1":{.....}, "2":{.....}}

How do I remove those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, when you call apply on `axis=1`, pandas creates a Series out of it and upcasts the values because it is a single Series. For example consider following Series:

```py
>>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3.2])
s
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.2
dtype: float64
```

As you can see, the entire series is converted to float because integer type can not hold all the values for the above series, similar is the case when you call apply on axis=1, it is same to :

```
df.iloc[0]
A    2.0
B    6.0
C    5.0
D    8.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

There's already an issue [DataFrame.apply unintuitively changes int to float because of another column](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23230) on github for this upcasting behavior of pandas `apply`.
So, one possible option for you is as I have mentioned in the comment, to call `to_json` on the entire dataframe as:

```py
>>>df.to_json(orient='index')
'{"0":{"A":2,"B":6,"C":5,"D":8.0},"1":{"A":6,"B":11,"C":2,"D":3.6},"2":{"A":1,"B":5,"C":7,"D":5.2}}'
```

A working solution for you may be using python's `json` module alongwith `DataFrame.to_json()`, but remember, it does the same thing twice so it may be a bit slow for a large dataframes, however, you will get the data in the rquired format:

```py
df['total'] = list(map(json.dumps, [*json.loads(df.to_json(orient='index')).values()]))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   A   B  C    D                                total
0  2   6  5  8.0   {"A": 2, "B": 6, "C": 5, "D": 8.0}
1  6  11  2  3.6  {"A": 6, "B": 11, "C": 2, "D": 3.6}
2  1   5  7  5.2   {"A": 1, "B": 5, "C": 7, "D": 5.2}
```